# Access Database Network Location Connect using c# code Password protected Multiple Users

Tags: ms-access, password-protection, multi-user

The question i put **seems old**, **but** my **requirements are quite complex and new**. Honestly did a lot of research, but still not able to find the perfect solution.
My requirements are as follows:

1. Access DB with single table, stored in network location.
2. Will be used by a tool written in C# code.(using connection string)
3. Will be used by multiple users'(say 50 max..).
4. Must be password protected.. as users' have access to shared network location, they can open the Access DB file manually.
5. If Split the database into backend and front end..to support multi user access, and if tried to protect with password, only able to protect the backend.The front end when i open to link with backend, after the linking is done, no password is required to open the front end.
6. I can't give a local copy to every user of tool, as c# code i can only give a permanent shared path location in connection string.
7. If i don't split the database, forums suggested can get data corruption issues.

Tell me if u require further clarifications on the requirements.

Comment: If you are looking for security use dedicated dbms like mysql or mssql which gives great deal of security out of the box

Comment: Yes i am looking also looking for security but a normal security would suffice.. my basic need is multi purpose users' say 50 accessing the data at a time ...